# Basic cout/cin question

Tags: c++, stdin

```
cin >> Input; {
 if(Input == "a")
  Position = "first";
 else if(Input == "b")
  Position = "second";
 else if (Input == "c")
  Position = "third";
 else if(Input == "Stop")
  break;
 }
```

After cin >> Input I have two more cin sections.  For some reason it skips over the getline for Name.  After I cin >> Input it shows Name: Status: and then does the getline for status.

```
  cout << "Name: ";
   getline(cin, Name);
   if(Name == "Stop")
   break;

 cout << "Status: ";
  getline(cin, Status);
  if(Status == "Stop")
  break;
```

Comment: Why do you have a break? I think you may need more complete code to understand how to answer this question.
Also, is Name and Status etc strings or char arrays? You've left a lot of your question to guessing.

Comment: Name and status are Strings.  The break is to exit the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
 cin.getline(whatever);
 cin.ignore(1, '\n');
```

See, when you've read some text from stdin, string end is determined by `\n` (by default). And when you hit Return in your console window, this symbol is skipped, but it is present. So, when you are trying to read the next string, it meets previously *forgotten* `\n` and terminates reading returning an empty string.

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/) for details.

Comment: 'is present' where? Please define 'forgotten'.

Comment: `\n` is present within the `stdin stream`. *forgotten* means `cin.getline()` *forgot* to read `\n` from the stream, so the last character in `whatever` string (see my answer' code) is `\0`

Comment: I partially agree on this, but don't think that getline() will leave `\n` behind, except if you're not hitting enter twice. Pipelining the text file to standart input, which contains windows crlf encodings is a little bit closer to truth.

Comment: @Andrejs agreed. But what's up with *nix terminals if so?  I'm not able to read strings normally without this 'fix'...

Comment: Found the problem and updated my answer. Perhaps that's your case also.

Comment: @shybovycha - there is no need to put an ignore where you're telling the OP to put it.  1) it's not the problem and 2) '\n' is already read from the stream by getline().  Don't know why your answer has been plused - it's completely in error.  Really, you didn't say anything correct in the whole thing.  Sorry if you're offended by that, but it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that most of the input operations will leave newline character in the input buffer (but not the `getline()`), more info is [here](http://objectmix.com/c/39782-does-getline-leave-/n-newline-input-stream.html).
In your case this line:

```
cin >> Input; {
```

will leave `/n` behind, which is feed later to:

```
getline(cin, Name);
```

Quick solution:

Replace `cin >> Input;` with `getline(cin, Input);`

Comment: HAH!  Beat you by an hour.  My answer also won't change what the "Input" string will contain.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> somevar` leaves behind a newline.  No matter what type `somevar` is, even if it's a std::string, the end of the line character is not read by that statement.  Thus when you get to the name part you read the end of the line for the `somevar` line, which is apparently empty.  Toss a getline in before the attempt to read name and it should be fine.